# Difference between Stephen Fry "Mythos" books

Tags: textual-history

I would like to buy the book *Mythos* by Stephen Fry. I know that he has published a trilogy where *Mythos* is the first book, followed by *Heroes* and *Troy*.

However, there seem to be several books by Stephen Fry called *Mythos*. [Google Books shows me four of those](https://books.google.com/books?q=editions:ISBN1452178917&id=bYbNvwEACAAJ):

[image]
On Amazon I can find the [blue one published by Penguin on 26th July 2018](https://amzn.eu/d/cz0YFEu) (464 pages).

And also the [white one published by Michael Joseph on 12th December 2017](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0718188748) (432 pages).

Is there any difference between these books? Or is it basically the same book published by different publishers? The title—*Mythos*—is the same, but the subtitle seems to be a bit different, so I would like to know: should I buy the blue one, the white one or the one from 2019 (the green one)?